# Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 in laravel installation on ubuntu

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-5

I'm getting this PHP warning when i try to run composer-

> Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe, somewhere in your *php.ini* you have a duplicated pdo extension inclusion. Open your *php.ini* and search for **extension = "pdo.so"** (or simply **pdo.so**). Remove any duplication found. Restart apache.

Comment: There is no any extension = pdo.so in my  php.ini file.

Comment: Got this. It  was under etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini & 20-pdo.ini. 
Fixed it. thanks..!!